# How do I properly set Angular Material v15 typography?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm upgrading to v15 and have the following:

```
$custom-typography-level: mat.define-typography-level(
  $font-family: 'Source Sans Pro, sans-serif',
  $font-size: 14px,
  $font-weight: 400,
  $line-height: 17px
);

$custom-typography: mat.define-typography-config(
  $headline-5: mat.define-typography-level(24px, 24px, 100), // h1
  $body-1: mat.define-typography-level(16px, 24px, 400), // body
  $headline-6: mat.define-typography-level(18px, 21px, 400), // h2
  $subtitle-1: mat.define-typography-level(16px, 19px, 400), // h3
);
```

Previously I had everything inside `$custom-typography: mat.define-typography-config` and passed that to `@include mat.all-component-typographies($custom-typography);` but that's not working anymore. The docs aren't as helpful. I just need to set the typography as my theme is being set in another file.

Answer (score 0):

This is because now the older angular material have legacy implementation so that's why you have to implement something like below

```css
// file should contain the input of all the custom/available fonts and their attachments and variations

@use "@angular/material" as mat;

@import "@angular/material/theming";

$custom-typography-config: mat.define-legacy-typography-config(
  $font-family: $font-family-semi-bold,
  $headline: mat.define-typography-level(22px, 22px, 600), /*<h1>*/
  $title: mat.define-typography-level(18px, 18px, 600),/*<h2>*/
  $subheading-2: mat.define-typography-level(  
  $font-family: $font-family-medium,
  $font-weight: 400,
  $font-size: 18px,
  $line-height: 1,
  $letter-spacing: normal), /*<h3>*/
  $subheading-1: mat.define-typography-level(
  $font-family: $font-family-medium,
  $font-weight: 400,
  $font-size: 14px,
  $line-height: 1,
  $letter-spacing: normal), /*<h4>*/
  $display-4: mat.define-typography-level(18px, 18px, 300, $letter-spacing: -0.05em), /*No Native Element*/
  $display-3: mat.define-typography-level(14px, 14px, 400, $letter-spacing: -0.02em), /*No Native Element*/
  $body-1: mat.define-typography-level(14px, 30px, 600), /* Body Text */
  $caption: mat.define-typography-level(14px, 30px, 500),/*No Native Element*/
  $button: mat.define-typography-level(14px, 30px, 500),
  $display-2: mat.define-typography-level(12px, 12px, 400, $letter-spacing: -0.005em), /*No Native Element*/
  $display-1: mat.define-typography-level(14px, 14px, 400), /*No Native Element*/
  $body-2: mat.define-typography-level(12px, 25px, 600), /*No Native Element*/
  $input: mat.define-typography-level(inherit, 1.25, 500),
);

//  The following line adds:
//    1. Default typography styles for all components
//    2. Styles for typography hierarchy classes (e.g. .mat-headline-1)
//  If you specify typography styles for the components you use elsewhere, you should delete this line.
//  If you don't need the default component typographies but still want the hierarchy styles,
//  you can delete this line and instead use:
//    `@include mat.legacy-typography-hierarchy($custom-typography-config);`
@include mat.all-component-typographies($custom-typography-config);
@include mat.legacy-core();
```